# cStringIO, reading bytes in chunks until EOF?

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I want to read a string in chunks of 1MB at a time, then upload it over XMLRPC, would this be the best way to do this? Is there anything I should watch out for?

```
while data.read(1048576) != None:
    data.seek(1048576, 1)
    if not rpc_srv.chunk_upload(tf_uuid, data_chunk):
        raise Exception('Failed to upload data.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the [`iter()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) with a sentinel to simplify your loop:

```
for data_chunk in iter(lambda: data.read(1048576), ''):
    if not rpc_srv.chunk_upload(tf_uuid, data_chunk):
        raise Exception('Failed to upload data.')
```

There is no need to `.seek()`, the `.read()` call already updates the position.

Comment: after implementing this, i've started getting "Memory Error"'s

Comment: @Jharwood: create a new question with a full traceback. It could be a totally unrelated problem somewhere else, or it could be the size of your cStringIO instances, for example.